# Getting , Error: 413 Payload too large when performing cy.percysnapshot()

Tags: cypress, visual-testing, percy

When executing the percy tests locally, i get the following error.

```
[percy] Encountered an error uploading snapshot: coikie_dialog_portal
[percy] Error: 413 Payload Too Large
```

Understand that the payload contains more information than its needed. My question here is that how to avoid this error. Also understand that the payload cannot be more than 15 MB

Also inorder to understand this error, I want to store and view the snapshots locally. How do I do that?

Could someone give me some ideas, or point me in the right direction to solve the above two issues that I am facing?

Thanks in advance!